# How do you draw a GdkPixbuf in python?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gdk, gdkpixbuf

Ok, so I'm trying to overlay a picture of a printer on top of a image (blueprint of floorplan).  I originally was looking at pixmaps, but had trouble finding anything about them in GTK 3.0 (found how to use them in pygtk, but not the same thing).  Anyways, here's what I have right now (I'm leaving out what I think to be insignificant parts of my code.  Also, the program builds fine, but I don't see any image overlay):

```
import cairo
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GdkPixbuf

class ClientGUI:
    def build_interface(self):

        # Window
        self.window = Gtk.Window(Gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL, title="SG Print Assist")
        self.window.add(self.topbox)
        self.window.set_name('window')
        self.window.show()

        self.hbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, spacing=6)
        # Department combobox; calls a function from another py file that retrieves the model to use.  In my program there are two other combo boxes that are dependent on this one.
        self.department_combo = Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_model_and_entry(self.logic.get_department_store())
        self.department_combo.connect("changed", self.on_department_combo_changed)
        self.department_combo.set_entry_text_column(0)
        self.hbox.pack_start(self.department_combo, False, False, 0)
        self.department_combo.show()
        self.hbox.show()

        # Image; will change to different images (floor plans) based on user input into combobox
        self.image = Gtk.Image()
        self.image.set_from_file("pics/City Logo.jpg")
        self.image.show()


        # XPM;  This isn't a printer, but for testing purposes it really doesn't matter.
        printer_xpm = [
            "48 48 64 1",
            "       c None",
            ".      c #DF7DCF3CC71B",
            "X      c #965875D669A6",
            "o      c #71C671C671C6",
            "O      c #A699A289A699",
            "+      c #965892489658",
            "@      c #8E38410330C2",
            "#      c #D75C7DF769A6",
            "$      c #F7DECF3CC71B",
            "%      c #96588A288E38",
            "&      c #A69992489E79",
            "*      c #8E3886178E38",
            "=      c #104008200820",
            "-      c #596510401040",
            ";      c #C71B30C230C2",
            ":      c #C71B9A699658",
            ">      c #618561856185",
            ",      c #20811C712081",
            "<      c #104000000000",
            "1      c #861720812081",
            "2      c #DF7D4D344103",
            "3      c #79E769A671C6",
            "4      c #861782078617",
            "5      c #41033CF34103",
            "6      c #000000000000",
            "7      c #49241C711040",
            "8      c #492445144924",
            "9      c #082008200820",
            "0      c #69A618611861",
            "q      c #B6DA71C65144",
            "w      c #410330C238E3",
            "e      c #CF3CBAEAB6DA",
            "r      c #71C6451430C2",
            "t      c #EFBEDB6CD75C",
            "y      c #28A208200820",
            "u      c #186110401040",
            "i      c #596528A21861",
            "p      c #71C661855965",
            "a      c #A69996589658",
            "s      c #30C228A230C2",
            "d      c #BEFBA289AEBA",
            "f      c #596545145144",
            "g      c #30C230C230C2",
            "h      c #8E3882078617",
            "j      c #208118612081",
            "k      c #38E30C300820",
            "l      c #30C2208128A2",
            "z      c #38E328A238E3",
            "x      c #514438E34924",
            "c      c #618555555965",
            "v      c #30C2208130C2",
            "b      c #38E328A230C2",
            "n      c #28A228A228A2",
            "m      c #41032CB228A2",
            "M      c #104010401040",
            "N      c #492438E34103",
            "B      c #28A2208128A2",
            "V      c #A699596538E3",
            "C      c #30C21C711040",
            "Z      c #30C218611040",
            "A      c #965865955965",
            "S      c #618534D32081",
            "D      c #38E31C711040",
            "F      c #082000000820",
            "                                                ",
            "          .XoO                                  ",
            "         +@#$%o&                                ",
            "         *=-;#::o+                              ",
            "           >,<12#:34                            ",
            "             45671#:X3                          ",
            "               +89<02qwo                        ",
            "e*                >,67;ro                       ",
            "ty>                 459@>+&&                    ",
            "$2u+                  ><ipas8*                  ",
            "%$;=*                *3:.Xa.dfg>                ",
            "Oh$;ya             *3d.a8j,Xe.d3g8+             ",
            " Oh$;ka          *3d$a8lz,,xxc:.e3g54           ",
            "  Oh$;kO       *pd$%svbzz,sxxxxfX..&wn>         ",
            "   Oh$@mO    *3dthwlsslszjzxxxxxxx3:td8M4       ",
            "    Oh$@g& *3d$XNlvvvlllm,mNwxxxxxxxfa.:,B*     ",
            "     Oh$@,Od.czlllllzlmmqV@V#V@fxxxxxxxf:%j5&   ",
            "      Oh$1hd5lllslllCCZrV#r#:#2AxxxxxxxxxcdwM*  ",
            "       OXq6c.%8vvvllZZiqqApA:mq:Xxcpcxxxxxfdc9* ",
            "        2r<6gde3bllZZrVi7S@SV77A::qApxxxxxxfdcM ",
            "        :,q-6MN.dfmZZrrSS:#riirDSAX@Af5xxxxxfevo",
            "         +A26jguXtAZZZC7iDiCCrVVii7Cmmmxxxxxx%3g",
            "          *#16jszN..3DZZZZrCVSA2rZrV7Dmmwxxxx&en",
            "           p2yFvzssXe:fCZZCiiD7iiZDiDSSZwwxx8e*>",
            "           OA1<jzxwwc:$d%NDZZZZCCCZCCZZCmxxfd.B ",
            "            3206Bwxxszx%et.eaAp77m77mmmf3&eeeg* ",
            "             @26MvzxNzvlbwfpdettttttttttt.c,n&  ",
            "             *;16=lsNwwNwgsvslbwwvccc3pcfu<o    ",
            "              p;<69BvwwsszslllbBlllllllu<5+     ",
            "              OS0y6FBlvvvzvzss,u=Blllj=54       ",
            "               c1-699Blvlllllu7k96MMMg4         ",
            "               *10y8n6FjvllllB<166668           ",
            "                S-kg+>666<M<996-y6n<8*          ",
            "                p71=4 m69996kD8Z-66698&&        ",
            "                &i0ycm6n4 ogk17,0<6666g         ",
            "                 N-k-<>     >=01-kuu666>        ",
            "                 ,6ky&      &46-10ul,66,        ",
            "                 Ou0<>       o66y<ulw<66&       ",
            "                  *kk5       >66By7=xu664       ",
            "                   <<M4      466lj<Mxu66o       ",
            "                   *>>       +66uv,zN666*       ",
            "                              566,xxj669        ",
            "                              4666FF666>        ",
            "                               >966666M         ",
            "                                oM6668+         ",
            "                                  *4            ",
            "                                                ",
            "                                                "
        ]

        # Pixbuf; the printer image I'm trying to overlay on the image.  Will probably create a class to represent the printer objects overlaying which contains position member variables.  Will then make a list of these to overlay all of them over the image at different positions.
        pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_xpm_data(printer_xpm)
        w, h = pixbuf.get_width(), pixbuf.get_height()

        surface = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, w, h)
        context = cairo.Context(surface)

        Gdk.cairo_set_source_pixbuf(context, pixbuf, 100, 100)
        context.paint()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: You don't have any GUI elements there. What kind of GUI do you want to have?

Comment: I already have the gui set up  (using a gtk window and gtk widgets), I just didn't include it because it has alot of widgets and I didn't want to take up a massive amount of space that wouldn't have related to the problem much. I'll add a few to the code.

Comment: Yes, please set up a minimal example that shows what you want to do. It's unusual to create a new cairo context for showing stuff on the screen, which is why I ask.

Comment: For docs, did you look at [the GDK reference](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk2/stable/)?

Comment: Thats the thing, if its unusual and there's a better way than cairo or pixbuf, I would love to know.  My whole goal is just to be able to overlay a small image over another large image that when clicked does something.  The large image will be changing based on user input.  I've had difficulty finding stuff online, as a big portion of everything is in C, which I'm not very proficient at yet.  @oldtechaa Yes I have, though its all in C.  I've been using  [this GDK Documentation](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/ListBox.html#Gtk.ListBox).

Comment: GDK isn't really meant for Gtk3; Cairo is. You could use a Cairo pattern loaded from a PNG for the same purpose and skip GDK altogether. For that matter, depending on the quality of the GTK binding for Python, C docs shouldn't be much different from Python ones (never used Python). Does Python have anything like [this](http://gtk2-perl.sourceforge.net/doc/pod/) for binding-specific docs that can be used with the C docs? I use the C docs (even though I don't know C well) and the Perl docs only for binding-specific changes. The C docs generally explain better and are more accurate.

Comment: Awesome!  thanks, I'll look into just using cairo then!  I havn't found anything quite the same, but I'll keep looking, and start trying to use the C docs more.  Thanks again.  I'll comment if I end up needing anymore help.

Comment: @SaniT404 look into `GdkDrawingArea` and using the `draw` signal. That'll give you the cairo context to draw on.